# Magento 2 Layered Navigation in Advance Search Result

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, filter, advanced-search

How can I add Layered Navigation in Advance Search result page(2 Column Left layout)?

How can I dot it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override **catalogsearch_advanced_index.xml** in your theme

From

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/view/frontend/layout/catalogsearch_advanced_index.xml
```

To

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_CatalogSearch/layout/catalogsearch_advanced_index.xml
```

Now change layout **1column** to **2columns-left**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

Now add container **sidebar.main** with **left navigation block**

Your final **catalogsearch_advanced_index.xml** like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Advanced Search</title>
    </head>
    <update handle="page_calendar"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
            <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\Category" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="layer/view.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State" name="catalog.navigation.state" as="state" />
            <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer" name="catalog.navigation.renderer" as="renderer" template="layer/filter.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Advanced\Form" name="catalogsearch_advanced_form" template="advanced/form.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="Magento_Theme::js/calendar.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Same way you need to override

1) catalogsearch_advanced_result.xml and

2) catalogsearch_result_index.xml

Comment: For me this shows the filters however they show all the filters and are not restricted to available options for the current collection. Is this normal?

Comment: Also for me, it show all the filters.

Answer (score 1):

Create new file `catalogsearch_advanced_result.xml` at path

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_LayeredNavigation/layout/
```

and add following code in file

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
            <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\Search" name="catalogsearch.advanced.leftnav" before="-" template="layer/view.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State" name="catalogsearch.advanced.navigation.state" as="state" />
                <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer" name="catalogsearch.advanced.navigation.renderer" as="renderer" template="layer/filter.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: I've tried all of the suggestions but I'm unable to display Layered Navigation on the advanced search index Magento 2.4.0