# Magento 2 Layered Navigation on Advanced Search Result Page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, layered-navigation, catalogsearch, search-result

I am able to enable 'Layered Navigation' on Catalog Search Result-Page "http://127.0.0.1/catalogsearch/result/index/" (see image below) by just enabling the storefront properties 'Use in Search Results Layered Navigation' of my two attributes.
[image]

**How can I enable same 'Layered Navigation' also on Catalog Search ADVANCED Result-Page** "http://127.0.0.1/catalogsearch/advanced/result/" **?**

ps: I have tried the solution from "[Magento 2 Layered Navigation in Advance Search Result](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176071/magento-2-layered-navigation-in-advance-search-result)"  but it gives me an error:

1. My Catalog Search ADVANCED Result-Page looks now (after trying above solution) like this:

[image]

As you can see the layered navigation price-filter shows all items from inventory, instead of just the 4 items that were found as result (see arrows).

2. When I click on a price-filter option like '€0.00 - €999.99 (5)', Magento displays an error:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you try using Magento 2 Layer Navigation Extension from Mageplaza

Answer (score 0):

When ever your try to filter product based on price using advanced search form this sent header value  like

> http://mage26.net/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?name=&sku=&description=&short_description=&price%5Bfrom%5D=1&price%5Bto%5D=10

Price value goes to array form like `from` and `to`.

But, if you try to filter layered navigation its goes to string  not a array like `from` and `to`

> http://mage26.net/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?description=&name=&price=-10000&short_description=&sku=

`-10000` means price  `0-10000`

`10000-` means price  `10000- above`.

I tried Below **Solution** its works fine.

Override this Model Class: `vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Advanced.php`.

Create di.xml file with in directory `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml`.

**di.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

        <preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Advanced" type="Clorida\AddFilter\Model\Rewrite\Advanced" />
    </config>
```

Then Create Advanced.php in with in `app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Rewrite/Advanced.php`

**Advanced.php**

```
        <?php
        /**
         * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
         * See COPYING.txt for license details.
         */
        namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Rewrite;

        use Magento\Catalog\Model\Config;
        use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility;
        use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
        use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute;
        use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\CollectionFactory as AttributeCollectionFactory;
        use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory as ProductCollectionFactory;
        use Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Advanced\Collection as ProductCollection;
        use Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\AdvancedFactory;
        use Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory;
        use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute as EntityAttribute;
        use Magento\Framework\Model\Context;
        use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
        use Magento\Framework\Registry;
        use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

        /**
         * Catalog advanced search model
         * @method \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Advanced getResource()
         * @method int getEntityTypeId()
         * @method \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Advanced setEntityTypeId(int $value)
         * @method int getAttributeSetId()
         * @method \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Advanced setAttributeSetId(int $value)
         * @method string getTypeId()
         * @method \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Advanced setTypeId(string $value)
         * @method string getSku()
         * @method \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Advanced setSku(string $value)
         * @method int getHasOptions()
         * @method \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Advanced setHasOptions(int $value)
         * @method int getRequiredOptions()
         * @method \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Advanced setRequiredOptions(int $value)
         * @method string getCreatedAt()
         * @method \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Advanced setCreatedAt(string $value)
         * @method string getUpdatedAt()
         * @method \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Advanced setUpdatedAt(string $value)
         *
         * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
         * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
         */
        class Advanced extends \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Advanced
        {
            /**
             * User friendly search criteria list
             *
             * @var array
             */
            protected $_searchCriterias = [];

            /**
             * Product collection
             *
             * @var ProductCollection
             */
            protected $_productCollection;

            /**
             * Initialize dependencies
             *
             * @var Config
             */
            protected $_catalogConfig;

            /**
             * Catalog product visibility
             *
             * @var Visibility
             */
            protected $_catalogProductVisibility;

            /**
             * Attribute collection factory
             *
             * @var AttributeCollectionFactory
             */
            protected $_attributeCollectionFactory;

            /**
             * Store manager
             *
             * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
             */
            protected $_storeManager;

            /**
             * Product factory
             *
             * @var ProductFactory
             */
            protected $_productFactory;

            /**
             * Currency factory
             *
             * @var CurrencyFactory
             */
            protected $_currencyFactory;

            /**
             * Advanced Collection Factory
             *
             * @var ProductCollectionFactory
             */
            protected $productCollectionFactory;

            protected  $logger;

            /**
             * Construct
             *
             * @param Context $context
             * @param Registry $registry
             * @param AttributeCollectionFactory $attributeCollectionFactory
             * @param Visibility $catalogProductVisibility
             * @param Config $catalogConfig
             * @param CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory
             * @param ProductFactory $productFactory
             * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
             * @param ProductCollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
             * @param AdvancedFactory $advancedFactory
             * @param array $data
             *
             * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
             */
            public function __construct(
                Context $context,
                Registry $registry,
                AttributeCollectionFactory $attributeCollectionFactory,
                Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
                Config $catalogConfig,
                CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory,
                ProductFactory $productFactory,
                StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
                ProductCollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
                AdvancedFactory $advancedFactory,
                \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $loggerinterface,
                array $data = []
            ) {
                $this->_attributeCollectionFactory = $attributeCollectionFactory;
                $this->_catalogProductVisibility = $catalogProductVisibility;
                $this->_catalogConfig = $catalogConfig;
                $this->_currencyFactory = $currencyFactory;
                $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
                $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
                $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
                $this->logger = $loggerinterface;
                parent::__construct(
                    $context,
                    $registry,
                    $attributeCollectionFactory,
                    $catalogProductVisibility,
                    $catalogConfig,
                    $currencyFactory,
                    $productFactory,
                    $storeManager,
                    $productCollectionFactory,
                    $advancedFactory,
                    $data
                );
            }

            /**
             * Add advanced search filters to product collection
             *
             * @param   array $values
             * @return  $this
             * @throws LocalizedException
             * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
             * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
             */
            public function addFilters($values)
            {
                $attributes = $this->getAttributes();
                $allConditions = [];

                foreach  ($attributes as $attribute) {
                    /* @var $attribute Attribute */
                    if (!isset($values[$attribute->getAttributeCode()])) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $value = $values[$attribute->getAttributeCode()];

                    $preparedSearchValue = $this->getPreparedSearchCriteria($attribute, $value);
                    if (false === $preparedSearchValue) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $this->addSearchCriteria($attribute, $preparedSearchValue);

                    if ($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'price') {
                        $rate = 1;
                        $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore();
                        $currency = $store->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
                        if ($currency != $store->getBaseCurrencyCode()) {
                            $rate = $store->getBaseCurrency()->getRate($currency);
                        }

                        if(is_array($value)){
                            $value['from'] = (isset($value['from']) && is_numeric($value['from']))
                                ? (float)$value['from'] / $rate
                                : '';
                            $value['to'] = (isset($value['to']) && is_numeric($value['to']))
                                ? (float)$value['to'] / $rate
                                : '';
                        }else{


                        }


                    }

                    if ($attribute->getBackendType() == 'datetime') {
                        $value['from'] = (isset($value['from']) && !empty($value['from']))
                            ? date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', strtotime($value['from']))
                            : '';
                        $value['to'] = (isset($value['to']) && !empty($value['to']))
                            ? date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', strtotime($value['to']))
                            : '';
                    }
                    $condition = $this->_getResource()->prepareCondition(
                        $attribute,
                        $value,
                        $this->getProductCollection()
                    );
                    if ($condition === false) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    $table = $attribute->getBackend()->getTable();
                    if ($attribute->getBackendType() == 'static') {
                        $attributeId = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
                    } else {
                        $attributeId = $attribute->getId();
                    }
                    $allConditions[$table][$attributeId] = $condition;
                }
                if ($allConditions) {
                    $this->_registry->register('advanced_search_conditions', $allConditions);
                    $this->getProductCollection()->addFieldsToFilter($allConditions);
                } else {
                    throw new LocalizedException(__('Please specify at least one search term.'));
                }

                return $this;
            }

            /**
             * Retrieve array of attributes used in advanced search
             *
             * @return array|\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\Collection
             */
            public function getAttributes()
            {
                $attributes = $this->getData('attributes');
                if ($attributes === null) {
                    $product = $this->_productFactory->create();
                    $attributes = $this->_attributeCollectionFactory
                        ->create()
                        ->addHasOptionsFilter()
                        ->addDisplayInAdvancedSearchFilter()
                        ->addStoreLabel($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId())
                        ->setOrder('main_table.attribute_id', 'asc')
                        ->load();
                    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
                        $attribute->setEntity($product->getResource());
                    }
                    $this->setData('attributes', $attributes);
                }
                return $attributes;
            }

            /**
             * Retrieve advanced search product collection
             *
             * @return Collection
             */
            public function getProductCollection()
            {
                if ($this->_productCollection === null) {
                    $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
                    $this->prepareProductCollection($collection);
                    if (!$collection) {
                        return $collection;
                    }
                    $this->_productCollection = $collection;
                }

                return $this->_productCollection;
            }

            /**
             * Prepare product collection
             *
             * @param Collection $collection
             * @return $this
             */
            public function prepareProductCollection($collection)
            {
                $collection
                    ->addAttributeToSelect($this->_catalogConfig->getProductAttributes())
                    ->setStore($this->_storeManager->getStore())
                    ->addMinimalPrice()
                    ->addTaxPercents()
                    ->addStoreFilter()
                    ->setVisibility($this->_catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInSearchIds());

                return $this;
            }

            /**
             * @param EntityAttribute $attribute
             * @param mixed $value
             * @return void
             */
            protected function addSearchCriteria($attribute, $value)
            {
                if (!empty($value)) {
                    $this->_searchCriterias[] = ['name' => $attribute->getStoreLabel(), 'value' => $value];
                }
            }

            /**
             * Add data about search criteria to object state
             *
             * @todo: Move this code to block
             *
             * @param   EntityAttribute $attribute
             * @param   mixed $value
             * @return  string|bool
             * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
             * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
             */
            protected function getPreparedSearchCriteria($attribute, $value)
            {
                if (is_array($value)) {
                    if (isset($value['from']) && isset($value['to'])) {
                        if (!empty($value['from']) || !empty($value['to'])) {
                            if (isset($value['currency'])) {
                                /** @var $currencyModel Currency */
                                $currencyModel = $this->_currencyFactory->create()->load($value['currency']);
                                $from = $currencyModel->format($value['from'], [], false);
                                $to = $currencyModel->format($value['to'], [], false);
                            } else {
                                $currencyModel = null;
                            }

                            if (strlen($value['from']) > 0 && strlen($value['to']) > 0) {
                                // -
                                $value = sprintf(
                                    '%s - %s',
                                    $currencyModel ? $from : $value['from'],
                                    $currencyModel ? $to : $value['to']
                                );
                            } elseif (strlen($value['from']) > 0) {
                                // and more
                                $value = __('%1 and greater', $currencyModel ? $from : $value['from']);
                            } elseif (strlen($value['to']) > 0) {
                                // to
                                $value = __('up to %1', $currencyModel ? $to : $value['to']);
                            }
                        } else {
                            return '';
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (($attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'select' ||
                        $attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'multiselect') && is_array($value)
                ) {
                    foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
                        $value[$key] = $attribute->getSource()->getOptionText($val);

                        if (is_array($value[$key])) {
                            $value[$key] = $value[$key]['label'];
                        }
                    }
                    $value = implode(', ', $value);
                } elseif ($attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'select' || $attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'multiselect') {
                    $value = $attribute->getSource()->getOptionText($value);
                    if (is_array($value)) {
                        $value = $value['label'];
                    }
                } elseif ($attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'boolean') {
                    $value = $value == 1
                        ? __('Yes')
                        : __('No');
                }

                return $value;
            }

            /**
             * Returns prepared search criterias in text
             *
             * @return array
             */
            public function getSearchCriterias()
            {
                return $this->_searchCriterias;
            }
        }
```

With in the Price Section, I have change like this.

```
   if ($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'price') {
            $rate = 1;
            $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore();
            $currency = $store->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
            if ($currency != $store->getBaseCurrencyCode()) {
                $rate = $store->getBaseCurrency()->getRate($currency);
            }

            if(is_array($value)){
                $value['from'] = (isset($value['from']) && is_numeric($value['from']))
                    ? (float)$value['from'] / $rate
                    : '';
                $value['to'] = (isset($value['to']) && is_numeric($value['to']))
                    ? (float)$value['to'] / $rate
                    : '';
            }else{


            }

        }
```

Then, **Clear cache**  and **Check it** let me know if you have issue.

Comment: How to add Layered navigation on Custom Product Collection? I am displaying products by brand using custom controller.

Comment: same problem plz suggest how to add layered Navigation in advance search result My M2 ver: 2.3.0 plz help my XML code below Comment screenshot > https://prnt.sc/rx7f9m

Comment: <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
            <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\Search" name="catalogsearch.leftnav" before="-" template="Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/view.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State" name="catalogsearch.navigation.state" as="state" />
                <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer" name="catalogsearch.navigation.renderer" as="renderer" template="Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/filter.phtml"/>
            </block></referenceContainer>